# Create Array from Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a Mysql table which contains a column of JSON data and a column with an amount. 
The goal is to extract the JSON data and the amount and build an array within the foreach loop. 
Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT `Amount`, `NewObject` FROM `mb_cart` WHERE `MyID` = '$id'";
$data_main = $db->query($sql);
```

Here is my statement that I am using to build the array:

```
foreach ($data_main as $transaction_main) {
    $json_decoded = json_decode($transaction_main);
    $cart = array('Amount' => $amount, 'CodeType' => $json_decoded->data->Type->data->codeType, 'Name' => $json_decoded->data->Name, 'SiteName' => $json_decoded->data->SiteName);
}
```

However when I run this, I am only returning only the first record set and the amount is blank, but the JSON data is listed. Appreciate any insight anyone cares to share.

Comment: What does `$db->query($sql);` return? An array or an iterator? See also [`array_push`](http://php.net/array_push) and the note there, [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) with a reference and [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/iterator_to_array).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to add `[]` to `$cart` array. WIth each run of foreach you're overwriting the variable $cart.

something like so would work:

```
foreach ($data_main as $transaction_main) {
    $json_decoded = json_decode($transaction_main);
        $cart[] = array('Amount' => $amount, 'CodeType' => $json_decoded->data->Type->data->codeType, 'Name' => $json_decoded->data->Name, 'SiteName' => $json_decoded->data->SiteName);
    }
```

Or if you wanted the array key to match that of the ID of each row:

**Note:** You will need to set $id variable somehow above IE: `SELECT id, amount` also note that you COULD potentially have issues if integer from `id` is non-unique.. eg(1,1,2,3,4,5,6) it will only show the last id of `1` instead of both (since key's are duplicates).

```
foreach ($data_main as $transaction_main) {
    $json_decoded = json_decode($transaction_main);
        $cart[$id] = array('Amount' => $amount, 'CodeType' => $json_decoded->data->Type->data->codeType, 'Name' => $json_decoded->data->Name, 'SiteName' => $json_decoded->data->SiteName);
    }
```

Comment: I only get   $names[$row["nombre"]] =  array('id' => $row["id"]);  -------Result--------->  key = Selección perfil , value = Array , why in value get array ?

Comment: You need to add [] to $cart array  <= this helps me a lot.  Thanks bro :)

Answer (score 11):

Your variable `$cart` is being overwritten in each loop because you are calling `array()` each time.

Instead, declare your array outside the loop, and just add values to it as needed:

```
$cart = array();
foreach ($data_main as $transaction_main) {
    $json_decoded = json_decode($transaction_main);
    $cart[] = array('Amount' => $amount, 'CodeType' => $json_decoded->data->Type->data->codeType, 'Name' => $json_decoded->data->Name, 'SiteName' => $json_decoded->data->SiteName);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
$cart=array();
foreach ($data_main as $transaction_main) {
    $json_decoded = json_decode($transaction_main);
        $cart[] = array('Amount' => $amount, 'CodeType' => $json_decoded->data->Type->data->codeType, 'Name' => $json_decoded->data->Name, 'SiteName' => $json_decoded->data->SiteName);
    }
```

You were treating the cart as a variable instead of array

Answer (score 4):

```
$cart = array();

foreach ($data_main as $transaction_main) {
    $json_decoded = json_decode($transaction_main);
    $cart[] = array('Amount' => $amount, 'CodeType' => $json_decoded->data->Type->data->codeType, 'Name' => $json_decoded->data->Name, 'SiteName' => $json_decoded->data->SiteName);
}

print_r($cart);
```

Answer (score 0):

the way to approach this is first create a variable `$cart = array();`
and then do `foreach();`
i have written code below please go through it

```
foreach($data_main as $transaction_main){
    $json_decoded = json_decoded($transaction_main);
    $cart[]=array('Amount' => $amount, 'CodeType' => $json_decoded->data->Type->data->codeType, 'Name' => $json_decoded->data->Name, 'SiteName' => $json_decoded->data->SiteName);
}
```